# Accesing to determinated Marker in a mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm using the Google Maps Android API V2 and I set an amount of markers in it.

I need get all markers from a MapView (really one of them). There is any way to do this? 
How can I iterate over the markers in the map? How can I locate one determinated marker?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is any way to do this?

Only if you have your own collection of markers.

> How can I iterate over the markers in the map?

Iterate over your own collection of markers.

> How can I locate one determinated marker?

Find it in your own collection of markers.

Maps V2 is largely a write-only interface for things like markers, polylines, and polygons. The data is not maintained in your process; rather, the data is sent via IPC over to the Google Play Services app. If you wish to use this data in the future, that is fine, but *you* need to hold onto it yourself in addition to supplying it to your `GoogleMap`.

Comment: I did it. I keep all markers in my List<Marker>() and get the element than I need by it's index. Thanks.